# Swap objects in array with react immutability helper

Tags: reactjs, immutability

I need to be able to switch items in an array on state using the immutability helper so as to not mutate state directly.

This is the behavior I am looking to achieve (i.e. switching positions 2 with 3)

```
[
    { key: 'banana'},
    { key: 'apple'},
    { key: 'orange'}
]
```

to become

```
[
    { key: 'banana'},
    { key: 'orange'},
    { key: 'apple'}
]
```

The code below is generating what I thought was going to accomplish this

```
immutableFruit = {}

let tempFruit = fruits[2]
immutableFruit[2] = { $set: fruits[1] }
immutableFruit[1] = { $set: tempFruit }

this.setState({fruits: immutableFruit})
```

When logging this to the console I get what I expect

```
1:
  $set: { key: 'orange' }
2:
  $set: { key: 'apple' }
```

So, in my mind, the state should reflect this change, but it doesn't something I didn't expect to, it switches one of the items, but fails to replace the other.

This is what the resulting state array actually looks like

```
[
    { key: 'banana'},
    { key: 'orange'},
    { key: 'orange'}
]
```

So, in short, I end up with two items in the list that are identical.

Is `$set` not the correct way to do this? When looking through the immutability helper documentation I didn't find any examples of this behavior or commands that perhaps are better fits for swapping elements in an array

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to [splice](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper#available-commands) twice:

```javascript
const fruits = [
    { key: "banana" },
    { key: "apple" },
    { key: "orange" }
];

console.log(fruits);

const swappedAppleAndOrange = 
    update(
        update(
            fruits, { $splice: [[1, 1, fruits[2]]] }
        ),
        { $splice: [[2, 1, fruits[1]]]}
    );

console.log(swappedAppleAndOrange);
```

This logs:

```
0: {key: "banana"}
1: {key: "apple"}
2: {key: "orange"}

0: {key: "banana"}
1: {key: "orange"}
2: {key: "apple"}
```

Comment: Thank you Cheruvim for checking. I ended up doing something along these lines I believe

Comment: This might be helpful, too: https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/array-splice-interesting-and-useful-13f38a9bb6b2

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @cherouvim's solution:

```
let fruits = [
    { key: "banana" },
    { key: "apple" },
    { key: "orange" }
];


function moveUp(key) {
    const idx = fruits.findIndex(f => f.key === key)
    if (idx < 1) return;

    fruits = update(
        update(
            fruits, { $splice: [[idx - 1, 1, fruits[idx]]] }
        ),
        { $splice: [[idx, 1, fruits[idx - 1]]]}
    );
}

function moveDown(key) {
    const idx = fruits.findIndex(f => f.key === key)
    if (idx === -1 || idx > fruits.length - 1) return;

    fruits = update(
        update(
            fruits, { $splice: [[idx + 1, 1, fruits[idx]]] }
        ),
        { $splice: [[idx, 1, fruits[idx + 1]]]}
    );
}

moveUp("apple");
console.log(fruits);

moveDown("apple");
console.log(fruits);
```